# Python: While loop updating LCD display

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm fairly new to Python although I do have some understanding of programming.
I am currently using Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi with an LCD display connected to it.
I can output to the display using the PIL library and the examples that came with the display.
What I am trying to do is display a value that updates over a period of time.
To break this down I created a while loop that displays a number, sleeps for 3 seconds, increments the number and then runs back through the loop checking the integer is not greater than 10.
However, the screen never updates the integer. To make sure it’s incrementing and testing correctly I put a print statement to the console and can see it incrementing.
I'm assuming it’s something to do with the while loop not refreshing the display but can't figure it out.  Sample code below.  Any help appreciated.

```py
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
    #import chardet
    import os
    import sys 
    import time
    import logging
    import spidev as SPI
    sys.path.append("..")
    from lib import LCD_2inch4
    from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont

    # Raspberry Pi pin configuration:
    RST = 27
    DC = 25
    BL = 18
    bus = 0 
    device = 0 
    i = 0
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


    try:
        # display with hardware SPI:
        disp = LCD_2inch4.LCD_2inch4()
        # Initialize library.
        disp.Init()
        # Clear display.
        disp.clear()
    
        # Create blank image for drawing.
        image1 = Image.new("RGB", (disp.width, disp.height ), "WHITE")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)
    
        logging.info("draw point")
        while i <10:
            test_var = "some text"
            draw.rectangle([(0,65),(140,100)],fill = "WHITE")
            draw.text((5, 68), test_var, fill = "BLACK")
            draw.text((5,150), str(i), fill = "BLACK")
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)
            image1=image1.rotate(0)
            disp.ShowImage(image1)
            time.sleep(3)
            i= i+1
            print(i)
            disp.clear()
        
        disp.module_exit()
        logging.info("quit:")
    
    except IOError as e:
        logging.info(e)    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        disp.module_exit()
        logging.info("quit:")
        exit()
```

Comment: Does the LCD screen get cleared in the first iteration of the `while` loop ? Btw, where is the initialization of `i` ?

Comment: Yes the screen is initialised and it displays the variable test_var and the i variable, its initilaised further up. Ive edit the above to include the whole code not just the snippet

Comment: After `image1=image1.rotate(0)`, *you are now working with an entirely new `Image` object*.  The `draw` object you have is still drawing into the original image, not the new one.

Comment: Thanks Jason got it working now

Comment: if you post this as an answer i will accept it